# Having trouble applying KNN

Tags: python, pandas, knn

I have a problem trying to use KNN
I'm applying the training and tests fit and I'm getting this error:
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4482, 2015]

Full error:

[image]

The problem is that the dataframe has already been treated and is without any problem

[image]

X_treino and y_treino shape:

[image]

Im going to put here all the code sequence I made and that is giving an error at the end:

```
X = wines_class.drop(['color'], axis=1)
y = wines_class['color']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_treino, y_treino, X_teste, y_teste = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.31, random_state=0)

print(X.shape,y.shape)
(6497, 12) (6497,)

from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def class_pontos(clf, y_predito):
  acc_treino = clf.score(X_treino, y_treino)*100
  acc_teste = clf.score(X_teste, y_teste)*100

  roc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predito)*100
  vn, fp, fn, vp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predito).ravel()
  cm = confusion_matrix(y_teste, y_predito)
  Correto = vp + vn
  Incorreto = fp + fn

  return acc_treino, acc_teste, roc, Correto, Incorreto, cm

#KNN

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
class_knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
class_knn.fit(X_treino, y_treino)

y_pred_knn = class_knn.predict(X_teste)

print(class_pontos(class_knn, y_pred_knn))
```

[Im sharing the csv here in this drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18_sOSIZZw9DCW7ftEKuOG4aIzGXoasFe?usp=sharing)

Comment: Would you mind displaying X_treino,y_treino shapes?

Comment: Please, post the full error stack.

Comment: In class_pontos, you have `vn, fp, fn, vp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predito).ravel()`, but probably you want `vn, fp, fn, vp = confusion_matrix(y_teste, y_predito).ravel()` (y_test -> y_teste). Same thing in `roc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predito)*100`.

Comment: print(X_treino.shape, y_treino.shape)
(4547, 12) (1950, 12)

Comment: i edit the question with shapes and the full error

Comment: Check the [docs of train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html): You probably should do `X_treino, X_teste, y_treino, y_teste = train_test_split(...`.

Comment: The error is not "at the end" (when trying to print the output from `class_pontos`) but before when it tries to fit the model (`class_knn.fit(X_treino, y_treino)`). Still, check the typos I marked on class_pontos so you don't get another error afterwards.

Comment: thx, i didnt see those 'e' that i didint type, that worked, ty, man i hate when i get lost on those details